# Update QStandardItem field text after delegate's setModelData

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, delegates

## Concept/Background

I am using model/view concept in my Qt program, where delegates are used to edit `QStandardItem`s in the QTreeView. The delegates consists of `QComboxBox`s.

For the `QComboBox` delegate, I re-implemented the following functions of `QItemDelegate`:

```
QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
```

`setModelData` finally write back the selected index to the model (`QStandardItemModel`). This is done by storing the QComboBox's selection index into the data of the QStandardItem. Afterwards, a final signal will be emitted from within setModelData to indicate the model to update all items in the view. This updated is needed due to dependencys between different items in the view (if one item value is changed, a item value somewhere else will be changed, too).

## Problem

Everything is working fine. The values are stored back to the model.
However, within the model, I am executing a function to update some QStandardItems text by using `setText` function.

And here comes my problem:
When I selected an item from the QComboBox, the combo will be closed, the signal gets emitted, the model updates all the relevant QStandardItem text. Exception: The item, which I have still selected, and which has been delegated by a QComboBox, gets no updated text. It seems that the delegate has not yet been destroyed and the `setText` function is not influencing the QStandardItem text value at all.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:
[image][image]
As you can see, through the update function of the model, it should have the format of ": ". However, even though it has been unfocused afterwards, the QComboBox value is still visible.

I could fix this problem by sending out the update request signal again, but I do not know when to do this.

FYI: If I choose another item for editing and finish it up by choosing a appropriate index, the update function is running over all items and of course also updates the last not updated item again (except of the last edited item as mentioned above).

Comment: Can't you just set the `Qt::DisplayRole` data from your `setModelData` function?

Comment: @hank: Unfortunately, no. I am using data to fill Qt::DisplayRole, which is only stored in the model (e.g. field names like RLRCRT - refer to the attached screenshot)

Comment: show code of `setEditorData`, `setModelData` and `createEditor`. there must be a problem!